# counting by cases over grouped time

Tags: sql, count, group-by, hive, case

I'm trying to count distinct ID's that appear in my data each week by versiontype and I'm not sure how to properly build the query.

I'm hoping to produce a table along the lines of:

```
      1.1     1.2     1.3    1.4
wk1     1       5       4      8
wk2     4       3       9      8
wk3     1       8       0      6
```

I tried crafting the query below, but it won't run as it requires the Case statement in the group by, which then won't accept a count().

```
  SELECT
  Case  when version like "1.1%" then Count(distinct ID)
     when version like "1.2%" then Count(distinct ID)
     when version like "1.3%" then Count(distinct ID)
     when version like "1.4%" then Count(distinct ID) end,
  CAST(((datediff(timestamp_pst,'2016-01-03') / 7)+1) as INT) as week_of_the_year
  FROM db.table
  where timestamp_pst >=  "2016-01-28"
  group by CAST(((datediff(timestamp_pst,'2016-01-03') / 7)+1) as INT)  
        order by week_of_the_year
```

Comment: Don't you want something like `SUM( CASE WHEN ... THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) x...` (although I would handle this kind of thing in application code)

Comment: @Strawberry - Will do this in app side even if the column list is fixed ?

Comment: @Strawberry If the IDs repeat which seams to be suggested COUNT(DISTINCT) will NOT yeild the same results as SUM(CASE WHEN THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  the latter would be equivalent to COUNT() where version like....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN version like '1.1%' THEN ID END)) as '1.1'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN version like '1.2%' THEN ID END)) as '1.2'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN version like '1.3%' THEN ID END)) as '1.3'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN version like '1.4%' THEN ID END)) as '1.4'
  CAST(((datediff(timestamp_pst,'2016-01-03') / 7)+1) as INT) as week_of_the_year
  FROM aws_d3.iaanalytics_detail
  where timestamp_pst >=  "2016-01-28"
  group by CAST(((datediff(timestamp_pst,'2016-01-03') / 7)+1) as INT)  
        order by week_of_the_year
```

You are wanting to use *"Conditional Aggregation"*.  Do do so the case statement actually goes inside the aggregate function.  Because you are wanting to `COUNT(DISTINCT)` you will actually need to do that either by utilizing the `DISTINCT` key word in the aggregation or by making a derived table so only distinct values are present as another answer suggests but as the only word it will save you from repeating is `DISTINCT` I don't see the need for complicating the matter by using a derived table.

Note that `SUM(CASE WHEN blah THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` will *NOT* work for you as that would sum all occurrences and not count distinct values.  Also Aggregate functions ignore null values and when you don't include an `ELSE` statement the value of a *case expression* will be `NULL` if not matched.

Comment: This worked perfectly, I'm working in Hive and it didn't like the as '1.1' but other than that it was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `COUNT()` aggregate function with conditional `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT
    week_of_the_year
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN version LIKE '1.1%' THEN id END) AS v1_1
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN version LIKE '1.2%' THEN id END) AS v1_2
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN version LIKE '1.3%' THEN id END) AS v1_3
  , COUNT(CASE WHEN version LIKE '1.4%' THEN id END) AS v1_4
FROM (
  SELECT
    DISTINCT
      id
    , version
    , CAST(((datediff(timestamp_pst,'2016-01-03') / 7)+1) as INT) as week_of_the_year
  FROM aws_d3.iaanalytics_detail
  where timestamp_pst >= '2016-01-28'
  ) t
GROUP BY week_of_the_year
ORDER BY week_of_the_year
```

Note, that the `DISTINCT` part of the query takes place within the derived table `t`. There is actually no need for the derived table, but I find it a cleaner solution because the `GROUP BY` clause doesn't repeat the same code and makes it more readable. This also introduces the distinct part not to be done within aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT
  SUM(Case  when version like "1.1%" then 1 ELSE 0 END) as '1.1',
  SUM(Case  when version like "1.2%" then 1 ELSE 0 END) as '1.2',
  SUM(Case  when version like "1.3%" then 1 ELSE 0 END) as '1.3', 
  SUM(Case  when version like "1.4%" then 1 ELSE 0 END) as '1.4',
  CAST(((datediff(timestamp_pst,'2016-01-03') / 7)+1) as INT) as week_of_the_year
  FROM aws_d3.iaanalytics_detail
  where timestamp_pst >=  "2016-01-28"
  group by CAST(((datediff(timestamp_pst,'2016-01-03') / 7)+1) as INT)  
        order by week_of_the_year
```

Comment: this will not work if ID can be duplicated as COUNT(DISTINCT) suggests